# Как сделать radiobutton для замены строки

Tags: javascript

Как сделать радиокнопку которая заменяет определенную строку в скрипте. 
Есть скрипт при нажатий который заменяет текст, так вот радиокнопка нужна чтобы сменить эту самую строку на другую.
На сайте есть несколько кнопок. При нажатий на который появляется текст.
В тексте есть слова которые надо изменять радиокнопками.
Как вы знаете js состоит из строк есть строка с этим словом, если сменить эту строку на другую, при нажатий на кнопку выйдет текст с словом который сменили.

строку я имею ввиду именно строку, 
var table{
'строка которую надо поменять'
'еще одна строка которую надо менять своей радиогруппой'
и т.д до закрытия
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Возможно вы это имели ввиду

```js
function chs(strval){
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = strval;
}
```

```html
<p id="text">Яблоко</p>
<input type="radio" id="rad2" name="rad" checked onclick="chs('Яблоко')">
<input type="radio" id="rad" name="rad" onclick="chs('Апельсин')">
```

Comment: извините я еще даже не новичек, но можно ли задать id на строку в js
не пинайте ногами я научусь когда нибудь

Comment: или можно использовать вместо id комментарий строки

Comment: строку я имею ввиду именно строку, var table{
'строка которую надо поменять'
'еще одна строка которую надо менять своей радиогруппой'
и т.д до закрытия}

Comment: Для строк нельзя, но можно поместить в тег <span id="elementId"></span>

Comment: Учтите что для id  может использоватся 1 раз, если вам нужно выбрать класс то выбирайте через document.getElementsByClassName('elementId')

Comment: Либо используйте substring

Comment: прошу прощения за этот нелепый вопрос. Я тогда только начинал учить js. Дело в том что я тогда не знал что такое массивы. Вопрос состоял в том что нужно было изменить элемент массива. Я это сделал уже. Спасибо за понимание

Comment: рад что помог.. или не помог =)